# Can "conceived" be used as "assumed"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

For example:

> Jack thinks he's responsible for killing his mother and thus for his uncle’s *conceived* hatred towards him.

Here, I mean to say that Jack *assumes* his uncle hates him (of course, Jack is sure, but it may not be the truth). And I think it'd be incorrect to say "...and thus for his uncle's *assumed* hatred towards him." Is *conceived* also incorrect?

I tried looking for other sentences that use *conceive* similarly, but those sentences seem to be using *conceive* to say hatred was *formed*.

Really, my goal is to say "...and thus for his uncle's hatred towards him, though Jack only assumes his uncle hates him--his uncle truly does not." Or something along those lines. I'm trying to make this sentence more concise by using *conceived* this way, but am not sure if this is the right approach. Suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

Try *perceived* instead of *conceived*.

Comment: @KristinaLopez so would it be correct to say, "Jack thinks he's responsible for killing his mother and thus for his uncle’s perceived hatred towards him." Or does this sentence require some rewording? Would there be any confusion as to *who* is perceiving the hatred?

Comment: @Blue, the sentence you just used in the comment above is perfectly clear to me with no confusion that he, himself, is responsible for his uncle's hatred of him (which, of course, without confirmation from the uncle, must remain his perception for now).

Comment: There's no real justification for switching to *perceived* unless OP is writing for people with limited knowledge of English. Personally, I think *conception* is a more appropriate term, since Jack has obviously *created this imaginary hatred entirely within his own mind*. It's not something that he's *perceived* with his [distorted] senses. But if *any* "attributive" adjective is inserted between *uncle's* and *hatred*, unavoidably it will grammatically associate with the uncle, not Jack. The fact that we know what the writer *means* doesn't make it "right".

Comment: I agree; I just ended up writing up a whole new sentence because it wasn't working out for me.

Answer (score 2):

OED says this under ***conceived*** (past participle adjective)...

> Admitted into, or originated in, the mind; imagined, thought of, etc.: *see the verb.*

As @Blue comments, the sentence itself probably needs rephrasing whether the specific word is *conceived/assumed/perceived/imagined/whatever*, since structurally it would seem the "assuming mind" being referenced is that of the uncle. But logic suggests it's probably supposed to be Jack's.

Comment: Ah, a different opinion. Well, I've literally spent the last 20 minutes trying to reword the sentence and I believe it isn't within my capability right now. If anyone has any suggestions, I would be eternally grateful, but for now, I think I'll just change it entirely.

Comment: @Blue: I'd do that. But I think the problem is if you switch it to anything like *"**and thus** he imagines his uncle hates him,"* still in the same sentence, there's a certain implication that this imaginary hatred is equally or even more important to Jack than the fact that he thinks he caused his mother's death. Which seems unlikely, whatever the rest of the context. I'd put off mentioning the "conceit" *(OED: a conception, notion, idea, thought; **obsolete**)* until you start a new sentence.

Comment: Well, the main point I'm trying to get across with this sentence is that he thinks his uncle hates him, which is obviously bad, because this misconception causes him to have an even worse misconception (that he killed his mother). The poor relationship between the two is the main focus though. 
I ended up just making the sentence "Jack believes he is responsible for the death of his mother and that his uncle despises him for this reason." Not satisfied with it, but better than the original sentence I struggled so much with.

Comment: @Blue: If that's what you meant, I think you *really* need a rewrite. It would never occur to me to suppose that the reason Jack thinks he caused his mother's death is *because* [he thinks] his uncle hates him. To me, your *"and thus"* implies precisely the opposite in terms of cause and effect.

Comment: Alright, would a sentence such as this remove all doubt to my meaning?: "Jack holds himself responsible for his mother’s death and believes that his uncle does as well, which he conceives as the reason for his uncle's hatred."

Comment: @Blue: Personally, I wouldn't try to cram it all into one sentence. You're talking about two different people's beliefs, about three different things - one of which is a *belief about a belief*. And note that even after everything you've written, I'm *still* not clear whether the uncle truly does hate Jack, or whether that's just some mistaken idea Jack has gotten into his head. Whatever - maybe you should take that one to writers.se

Comment: Perceived, imagined, and assumed all could fit, but have slightly different meanings ("perceived" means behaviour looks like hatred but might have an innocent reason, "imagined" suggests you've been blowing it up in your mind out of nothing, and "assumed" is more like prejudice or explicitly without evidence).

Answer (score 1):

No.  I can't find any such usage that's valid, nor does "conceive" show up as a synonym for "assume" in the free online thesaurus.  What's wrong with "assumed" when you mean "assumed"?

How I might structure it-- there are scads of ways:

> Jack thinks he's responsible for killing his mother, and that his uncle's knowledge of this has caused his uncle to hate him.  However, Uncle Shloim later reveals that this is not the case, by cooking Jack a delicious, unpoisoned bass.

Conciseness is nice, but it ain't everything.

Comment: Thanks for the creative example! I think I'll use it.

I know conciseness isn't everything, but my teacher stressed that I need to work on being more concise, so I'm trying really hard to right now as I'm writing my essay... I feel like it's detracting from my work (as shown in my attempt at this messed up sentence), but oh well. I digress.

Answer (score 0):

Can you reword such that your use of *conceived* better indicates 'apparent genesis of'?
i.e.,

The act that leads Jack to believe he killed his mother, *conceives* in his Uncle a hatred...?

Comment: My problem with this is that it doesn't indicate that Jack's uncle's hatred is only *conceived* by Jack. So his uncle doesn't really hate him. I'm trying to use *conceive* as in "to hold as an opinion; think; believe"

Answer (score 0):

'interpretation' or 'impression' or '*ception' would work if you STOP REFERENCING HATRED in unqualified manner which makes it objective, setting you up for contradiction trying to frame it as a subjective conjecture using any synonym.  Remember, if Jack's wrong, append 'mis-' to your synonyms.

Comment: +1 for the point about ***pre***pending "mis-" to the chosen term, to explicitly indicate that Jack is ***mis***taken in his belief.

Answer (score 0):

I often complain about the excessive use of pronouns.

Eventually, I have come to the conclusion  that Jack thinks that he (Jack) is responsible for killing/the death of his own mother and that his maternal uncle (i.e. her brother) hates him (Jack) for this reason.

At this stage we do not know (i) if Jack **has** killed his own mother or (ii) if the uncle really hates him or, (iii) if the uncle **does** hate Jack, that it is Jack's mother's death that is the reason for uncle's hatred.

Thus:

*Jack thinks he's responsible for killing his own mother and that as a result Jack's maternal uncle’s has **conceived** a hatred towards him.*

**Conceive**: OED

> **I. Senses relating to mental or emotional states, or their expression.**
>
> **1.a.** transitive. **To form (an intention, design, etc.) in the mind or (in early use) the heart; to plan, devise, or formulate.**
>
> 1931   J. Sherrod Scapegoats 49   *One of the most vicious policies
> ever conceived.*
>
> 1999   Guardian 5 Nov. a15/3   *He finally conceives an undignified
> plan to destroy her political career.*

However,

> **4.a.** transitive. **†To become affected or possessed by (an emotion) (obsolete); to form or develop (an attitude or feeling) towards a person or thing.**

Note that this is marked obsolete. However, we have recent usage - the 2005 quote is particularly germane:

> 1974   E. L. Doctorow Ragtime (1976) i. 6   *He had conceived an enormous interest in the works and career of Harry Houdini.*
>
> 2005   N.Y. Rev. Bks. 1 Dec. 56/2   *She conceived a stealthy hatred of..people who chitter-chatter and fritter life away.*